# Find N Most Frequent Words in a File and How to Handle Hyphen?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, files

Let's say we have a file having following text:

```
hello hel-
lo world wor-
ld test test he-
lo words words
```

If we just use the space as the delimiter, we would have

```
hello: 1
world: 1
wor:1
ld:1
he: 1
hel-: 1
test:2
lo: 2
words: 2
```

In other words, how do we process the word separated by 2 lines using a hyphen and treat it as one word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sed ':1;/-$/{N;b1};s/-\n//g;y/ /\n/' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl is handy for this:  the -0777 switch will slurp the entire file into a single string

```
perl -0777 -ne '
   s/-\n//g;                  # join the hyphenated words
   $count{$_}++ for split;    # count all the words
   while (($k,$v) = each %count) {print "$k:$v\n"}
' file
```

```
world:2
helo:1
hello:2
words:2
test:2
```

The output will be in no particular order.

---

And here's a more obscure one: [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl). tclsh does not have a nice `-e` option like other languages, so one-liners are more work. The advantage with this is that the order of the words in the file is preserved.

```
echo '
    set fh [open [lindex $argv 1] r]
    set data [read -nonewline $fh]
    close $fh
    foreach word [split [string map {"-\n" ""} $data]] {
        dict incr count $word
    }
    dict for {k v} $count {puts "$k:$v"}
' | tclsh -- file
```

```
hello:2
world:2
test:2
helo:1
words:2
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tr` + `sed` + `datamash` pipeline:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' <file | sed '/-/N;s/-\n//' | datamash -s -g1 --output-delimiter=':' count 1
hello:2
helo:1
test:2
words:2
world:2
```